# Same functions in plot but in different ways get different graph

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, documentation

According the documentation in Wolfram, Plot uses in below way,

```
Plot[f,{x,xmin,xmax}]
```

So, there is my original code.

```
k = 2;
Plot[Sum[Binomial[n, i] E^-(0.1*i)*(1 - E^(-0.1))^(n - i), {i, k, n}], {n, 2, 15}]
```

I got graph like this,
[image: wrong result]

But if I put the function out of Plot,

```
k = 2;
f1 = Sum[Binomial[nn, i] E^-(0.1*i)*(1 - E^(-0.1))^(nn - i), {i, k, 
    nn}];
Plot[{f1}, {nn, 2, 15}]
```

I got graph like this,

[image]

What causes the different graphs?
Was my first approach wrong?

Comment: It's because `Sum[Binomial[nn, i] E^-(0.1*i)*(1 - E^(-0.1))^(nn - i), {i, k, nn}]` evaluates to a formula that is a smooth function of `nn`.  Inside `Plot` the variable is substituted with a value such as `4.5` before the sum is evaluated.  When `nn` becomes greater than `5.`, suddenly another term is added and the sum jumps in value.  I don't know which way you wanted it.  Perhaps `DiscretePlot` is really what you should use?

Comment: Thanks! Yes,  DiscretePlot with the function inside gets the right graph. _When nn becomes greater than 5., suddenly another term is added and the sum jumps in value._What does this mean?

Comment: `Sum[f[k], {k, 4.5}]` --> `f[1] + f[2] + f[3] + f[4]`, `Sum[f[k], {k, 4.9}]` --> `f[1] + f[2] + f[3] + f[4]`, `Sum[f[k], {k, 4.99}]` --> `f[1] + f[2] + f[3] + f[4]`, etc....Then `Sum[f[k], {k, 5}]` --> `f[1] + f[2] + f[3] + f[4] + f[5]`, and you suddenly get another term.

Comment: Your summations up to `4.5`, `4.9`, `4.99`, etc. have the same number of terms.  They would be constant, except the formula in your sum also depends on `nn`.

Comment: Or `Evaluate` the `Sum` inside the Plot`, i.e., `Plot[Evaluate@
  Sum[Binomial[n, i] E^-(0.1*i)*(1 - E^(-0.1))^(n - i), {i, k, 
    n}], {n, 2, 15}]`